# Connecting flights with partner airlines

Tags: transit, airlines

I bought a ticket with an online travel agency and at check-in, at the airport, the airline company informed me they don't do point-to-point check-in with KLM and that I would have to do 7 days quarantine in Bangkok.

However, Bangkok Airways are a partner with KLM and I already have a ticket with KLM flying out of Bangkok today.

So my question is if I buy a ticket with Bangkok Airways, can they check in my bag and give me boarding passes all the way to my destination even though I have two separate tickets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can they? Sure. Will they? No. See [here](https://www.bangkokair.com/through-check-in):

> When passenger travel with two separate tickets, Bangkok Airways will no longer through-check passenger and bags to the end destinations on the secondary separate ticket. Please see more details in Separate Ticket Policy